# How to bind socket to a specific network interface and to any ports and any IP on that interface

Tags: sockets, network-programming, ipv6, communication

I have a hardware attached to my RPI board running Linux distro. This hardware & its associated Host stack has created a network interface called wpan0 and assigned some IPV6 addresses to it (I am able to ping the IPV6 address from a remote device in the same network)

Now, I want to enable data communication to this interface to any IPV6 IP assigned to the interface. How do I create and bind a socket to this interface? Also, I want to listen to any ports on this interface. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

How you create a socket depends on the language you use (you didn't specify), but when you want to bind a socket to ANY interface the IPv4 way is to listen to IP **0.0.0.0**, the IPv6 equivalent is **::/0**, that means all zeros/0 bits CIDR mask.

Redirecting all ports to one is less of a code issue and requires some hands on with **IPTables** and **Prerouting** (you can write some code that appends that to your conf file though), here is an example:
https://serverfault.com/questions/616535/iptables-destination-ip-and-port

Comment: Just some friendly advice: The IPv6 equivalent of `0.0.0.0` is simply `::`. The IPv6 equivalent of the Ipv4 default route, `0.0.0.0/0`, is `::/0`. The CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing) reference is only relevant to IPv4 that used to have network classes, but IPv6 has never had network classes, so CIDR is redundant.